# Excel Web browser

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-online

I am trying to group data from dates to quarter in excel with pivot table . But while working in excel on web . I cannot find any Grouping option. Plz tell me how to solve it. Also Combo charts are unavailaible. I mean line and column chart.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy5Tf.png)

I tried to use group option from data tab. but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Sadly excel (for the web) does not have grouping options or combo charts. although you can still use a formula like this this:**

1. insert a new column next to the date column.
2. in the first cell of the new column, enter the formula =ROUNDUP(MONTH(A2)/3,0)
3. drag the formula down to the bottom of the data set
4. now you have a column that shows the quarter number for each date and you can
   use this column in your pivottable to group by quarter.

**and for the combo chart:**

1. Select the data for both the line chart and the column chart
2. create a column chart for the data you want to show as columns
3. create a line chart for the data you want to show as a line
4. copy the line chart and paste it on top of the column chart
5. adjust the formatting of the chart as needed to make it look like a combination chart.

Hope it works out.

Comment: Can you plz show me through example